# What are alternatives for Menumeters on El Capitan?

Tags: software-recommendation, macos

Menumeters no longer works on El Capitan ([see here](http://www.ragingmenace.com/software/menumeters/#requirement)), what are some alternatives? I just want to see my network and CPU stats.

Answer (score 185, accepted):

I just ported MenuMeters for El Capitan, please go to http://member.ipmu.jp/yuji.tachikawa/MenuMetersElCapitan/.

Comment: It is working :)

Comment: Works for me too - you rock!

Comment: Yuji -- did you go over a bandwidth limit? Page load is timing out.

Comment: In case anyone is looking for it and unable to access the linked site, here's the zip file that was available for download before it went down. I'll be happy to remove this when you get back online.
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8413228/MenuMeters_1.9.zip It's also possible to install by downloading the xcode project from [GitHub](https://github.com/yujitach/MenuMeters)

Comment: To @yuji - I am receiving errors when I install MenuMeters_1.9 prefpane. I just get "Could not load MenuMeters preference pane." Thoughts?

Comment: Can anyone help me with simple step by step for compiling this with Xcode7.0.1 on El Cap? I cloned the Git repo but when I build the project I can't find the PrefPane anywhere, not even a "Build" folder.  I admit I don't know what I'm doing...

Comment: @JaredMiniman Try to logout and log back in

Comment: you da man bro, also wish it had an update rate faster than .5s

Comment: Worked on the first time, even without logout/login :-)

Comment: Best thing ever!

Comment: I had the pref-page open, and I needed to close and re-open it. But then it works!!

Comment: You, Sir, are a scholar and a gentleman.

Comment: Interesting that the MenuMeters website says: "Unless Apple makes the signature restriction optional, it is not clear that MenuMeters in its present form can ever be made compatible with OS X 10.11."

Comment: Thanks for your work! Odd question but how to delete from pref pane (remove your tool?)

Comment: Dear Kristyn, just right-click the MenuMeters icon within the System Preferences and choose to remove it.

Comment: It's working on Sierra 10.12.5 :)

Answer (score 9):

iStat Menus has a beta going for El Capitan right now - it's a paid app, but will definitely do what you want. [See link here.](https://twitter.com/bjango/status/611786084918259716)

Comment: I was hoping to find something on the free side. However, if this is the only app that does it, I'll fork over some cash. Thanks!

Comment: Could you edit your comment to link to the tweet that gives the download link, https://twitter.com/bjango/status/611786084918259716, instead of a direct download link? It wasn't obvious to me that the t.co link was going to be a download of the app itself.

Comment: @JustinAnderson --> http://s3.amazonaws.com/bjango/files/istatmenus5/beta/istatmenus5.11b12.zip

Answer (score 6):

There are also some cheaper alternatives:

- http://seense.com/menubarstats/
- http://www.sparkfield.com/products/colossus/
- https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/statswidget-plus/id1022329158?mt=12

hope it helps!
:-)

Answer (score 1):

If you want some free apps, you might want to check this out: iStat Pro Widget 4.92.

It's the same as iStat Menus suggested by @Mikey T.K., but:

- pros: free
- cons: discontinued

And it's not a proper app: as its name suggests it's a widget, so you'll find it in the Dashboard.